# Digitalocean DOCTL and Bash looping - stumped

Tags: bash, digital-ocean

This script works so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to create digitalocean droplet snapshot using their CLI, doctl.

# Function to set variable for snapshot name as date/time of creation.
timestamp() {
NAME=$(date)
}

timestamp

doctl compute droplet-action snapshot --snapshot-name "$NAME" 80750079
```

The script works with the result being a droplet snapshot with the date/time of creation as the name.
However, I need to keep only 12 snapshots.

Somehow I need to count the number of existing snapshots and when I have 12, delete the oldest and add a new one.

How can I achieve that?

I run the script every two hours.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds great; what have you tried?

Comment: Can't you just use `logrotate` for that?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer my own question after realizing I could take the doctl output and  make an array. The stumbling block was in not realizing that.

Here is the code for any future reference. Perhaps it will help someone.
BTW, doctl is the digital ocean CLI.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &> do_snapshot.log

timestamp() {
NAME=$(date)
}

timestamp

SNAPSHOTS=$(/snap/bin/doctl compute image list-user --format "ID" --no-header | wc -l)

if [ "$SNAPSHOTS" -gt 23 ]; then
mapfile -t IDLIST < <(/snap/bin/doctl compute image list-user --format "ID" --no-header)

OLDEST=${IDLIST[0]}

/snap/bin/doctl compute image delete "$OLDEST"
fi

/snap/bin/doctl compute droplet-action snapshot --snapshot-name "$NAME" 8Xxxxxx0079

mail -s "Digital Ocean Hourly Snapshot" my email@gmail.com < do_snapshot.log

rm do_snapshot.log

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array. Here is an example using simple bash commands.

```
declare -a alphabet=(); 
index=0;
for letters in {a..z}; do     
    alphabet[$((index++))]=$letters; 
    sleep 1; 
done
```

- To see all the elements in an array: `printf '%s\n' "${alphabet[@]}"`
- To access a particular element, use it's index. For example to access the letter b you could do: `printf '%s\n' "${alphabet[1]}"`
- Note: an array's index begins at 0.
- You can check the length of an array (i.e. the total number of elements) with `${#alphabet[@]}`

Comment: I follow your example but I will have to figure out how to get an array of the snapshots using doctl. Thanks for the direction toward using an array though :)

Comment: I have no idea what `doctl` is or what the output of your droplet snapshot might look like. But regardless, if you're wanting to store, index, and replace multiple values, arrays are the way to go. Bash syntax can make them seem more complicated than they actually are.